# redirect a domain using htaccess permenantly

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns, permanent

I am having a site with two domains pointing to the same site. 
Lets say `domain1.com` & `domain2.com`

I want to do a permanent redirect of the `domain1.com` to `domain2.com`, so that anyone who visit the site from domain1 even if Google crawler, it should be redirected to the domain2. I want to do this from htaccess. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

put in your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)domain1.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```